# why fstream.read work and not >>?

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm wondering why i cannot use the `>>` operator of an `std::ifstream` to read an unsigned int from a binary file.

```
#include <fstream>

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
        if(in.fail())
            return -1;

        unsigned int atom_size = 0;

        in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&atom_size), 4);
        in >> atom_size;

        return 0;
    }
```

When I use `in.read` I get the value that I wanted, but when I use the `>>` operator my atom_size variable doesn't change. Why ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently you're reading a binary file.  The `read` command literally copies the requested number bytes from the file into the memory indicated by pointer you provided.  The `>>` operator expects to find ASCII text to be converted into an integer.  The two operations simply aren't the same.

Comment: If the OP is reading a binary file, shouldn't the stream be opened in binary mode?

Comment: @DyP, probably for portability and strict correctness, yes.  On a lot of systems it simply doesn't matter.  The difference between text & binary modes usually has to do with handling of line endings and so forth.  In OP's simple program there's unlikely to be a difference.

Comment: It might be good to mention that the Standard distinguishes ***Formatted input functions*** and that `operator>>(unsigned int& val);` is one of these, while `get`, `ignore`, and `read` are ***Unformatted input functions***.  Naturally a *Formatted input function* doesn't work without formatted input.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between reading the binary data as a character vs reading the data as an integer. For example, the **number** 5 is 00000101. The **character** '5' is 00110101.

The `>>` operator is reading **characters**, so when it sees 00110101, it assumes this is the character for 5. If you try to read into an `int`, then `>>` will correctly convert this to 00000101 and store that value in the int. But if the character is e.g. a letter like `a`, which does not correspond to a valid int, `>>` will fail silently (it won't crash, but it will return `false`).

In your binary file, for example maybe the number 5 was stored as 00000101, but `>>` thinks it is supposed to read this as a **character** (which is the ENQ character). This cannot be converted to an int, so the line `in >> atom_size;` will silently fail. Actually, it returns a `istream&` that can be converted to a `bool` so you can check if it failed like so:

```
if(!(in >> atom_size)) {
  cout << "Failed to read into atom_size" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Actually, it returns a reference to the stream, which has an explicit conversion to bool so you can check if it failed.  If `operator>>` returned a `bool` then you couldn't say `cin >> a >> b >> c`

Comment: @BenVoigt Absolutely, thank you for pointing that out. Slightly changed my description to take that into account

Comment: A formatted input function is a formatted input function no matter if the stream is in binary or text mode. It'll still use the locale's `num_get` facility to read and convert the number, which for most compilers with the default C locale will do the ASCII text -> `int` conversion.

Comment: @DyP so opening it as binary won't help? Is there a way to get around this, i.e. still use `>>` to read?

Comment: @maditya I think there are ugly tricks to use `>>` to read an `int` from a binary file/stream, but they are far uglier than just to use `read`. Additionally, using `read` immediately shows you're dealing with binary/unformatted data.

Comment: @DyP makes sense. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Binary mode doesn't help to use `>>` for this purpose, but IMO it should be used when reading from binary files.